# how to break on first validation fail on custom validation attributes on multiple attribute properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I have three custom validation attributes : Req, FixedLen and Number. I wrote custom validation attributes to save my self from writing error message every time I use them because my website is in Persian and i need Persian messages. this is how I use them in my models :

```
[Req]
[FixedLen(8)]
[Number]
public string phone { get; set; }
```

the problem is even if the first attribute detects that something is wrong with the data the other two attributes are triggered. so even if the posted data is null, my FixedLen attribute invokes the isValid method. what i want is that on the first validation fail, the validation of this attribute breaks and my next attribute to be validated.

edit :

```
public class ReqAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private string error_msg = "فیلد الزامی";
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value == null || value.ToString().Trim().Length == 0)
            return new ValidationResult(error_msg);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using a Resource file for the error messages? And what are you custom validation attributes? (and if your data is `null` and your `FixedLen` attribute code is validating, then your code is wrong!)

Comment: in isValid method I return null if the data is not null, is that right?

Comment: If the property nullable and the value is `null`, your `IsValid` method should return `ValidationResult.Success`(but you have not shown any code or explained why you need custom validation attributes)

Comment: check the edit, when the value is null I return ValidationResult, but this does not keep other validation attributes from firing.